# Do photons have/contribute to mass?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, special-relativity, photons, mass-energy

Do electrons gain mass by absorbing photons during excitation and releasing them by returning to the ground state?

Do photons have mass in the form of energy by $E=mc^2$?

Answer (score 4):

Electrons don't gain mass when they hop up an energy level--we know this because we calculate the electron levels assuming a particular electronic mass, so if the electron mass changed, it would also have a different energy level.

Photons are massless. Nothing that has mass can travel at the speed of light. Now, $E = mc^2$ is not a complete formula. The full formula is $E = \sqrt{p^2 c^2 + m^2 c^4}$, which for photons reduces to $E = p c$, where $p$ is momentum. So photons have energy, but not mass.

Comment: Yaa but p=m×v then where is mass

Comment: That equation is non-relativistic, and doesn't apply to light. Even in classical electrodynamics, the EM field carries momentum, but doesn't have mass.

Answer (score 0):

Photon never come to rest with respect to any reference frame, so its mass has no meaning. It always travels at the speed of light $c$.
It has no mass so it does not feel no force. Thought it has relativistic mass,but don't confuse it with invariant mass which is zero for photon. You can derive $E^2=(pc)^2+E°^2$ from $E=mc^2$ where $p$ is the momentum, and $E°$ is the rest energy.

Rest energy for photon=0, so for photon $E=pc$. We know from quantum theory $E=h\nu$, where $\nu$=frequency. So, $E = pc = h\nu$.

Comment: So energy of photon remains constant if we not changes its frequency??

Comment: Yes,if frequency is not changes then energy of photon remains same.